# showing the vectors are perpendicular

Tags: linear-algebra

The question:
1) The slopes of the arrows from $(0,0)$ to $(v_1, v_2)$ and $(w_1, w_2)$ are $v_2/v_1$ and $w_2/w_1$.

2) Suppose the product $(v_2, w_2)/(v_1, w_1)$ of those slope is $-1$.

3) Show that $v\cdot w = 0$ and the vectors are perpendicular.

I know the dot product of orthogonal and orthonormal vectors is $0$.
I also know the product of the slopes of orthogonal vectors is always $-1$. 
But the answer given to the problem is as follows. ( I broke it into steps so that I can explain why I am lost!)

1) If $(v_2, w_2) /  (v_1, w_1) = -1$ then, $(v_2, w_2) = (-v_1, w_1)$.....Understood

2) or $= (v_1w_1 + v_2w_2) = v\cdot w = 0$ .........unable to understand. I do understand $(v_1w_1 + v_2w_2) = 0$. But I am lost how I can insert $v\cdot w$ in the middle and where did it come from?

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

By **definition** $v.w=v_1w_1+v_2w_2$.

Comment: oops! I knew it too! I guess I just got into one of those "self-induced confusion".

Comment: Thank you Mr. Murthy